# Jmagick: configure: error: 'Unable to find ImageMagick header files' on MacOS

Tags: imagemagick, jmagick

I am new to jmagick and image magick.

I have image magick 7.0.8-14 installed on mac.when I try to configure Jmagick, I get below error. I referred many posts to resolve the error, but nothing helped.

```html
./configure --with-java-home=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current --with-magick-home=/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.8-14/
checking build system type... i686-apple-darwin17.7.0
checking host system type... i686-apple-darwin17.7.0
checking target system type... i686-apple-darwin17.7.0
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking for getconf... /usr/bin/getconf
checking whether large file support needs explicit enabling... no
checking for X... no
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking jni.h usability... yes
checking jni.h presence... yes
checking for jni.h... yes
checking for java... /Users/merla/.jenv/shims/java
checking for javac... /Users/merla/.jenv/shims/javac
checking for javah... /Users/merla/.jenv/shims/javah
checking for jar... /Users/merla/.jenv/shims/jar
checking for javadoc... /Users/merla/.jenv/shims/javadoc
checking for MagickCore-config... /usr/local/bin/MagickCore-config
checking magick/api.h usability... no
checking magick/api.h presence... no
checking for magick/api.h... no
configure: error: 'Unable to find ImageMagick header files'
```

Could someone help with installation

Comment: Try installing `libMagick6.4.0-devel` from http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libMagick6.4.0-devel

Comment: The `magick/api.h` is from ImageMagick-6. Looks like you installed ImageMagick-7. Try `brew install imagemagick@6`

Comment: theimagemagick@6 is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because this is an alternate version of another formula.
If you need to have imagemagick@6 first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/imagemagick@6/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
For compilers to find imagemagick@6 you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/imagemagick@6/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/imagemagick@6/include"

For pkg-config to find imagemagick@6 you may need to set:
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/imagemagick@6/lib/pkgconfig"

Comment: what should I add to ./bash-profile?

Comment: I got it resolved